# Argument 'publishMessageFormTagController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

`app.js`

```
  .state('publishmsg/new-message', {
      url: '/publishmsg/new-message',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageController'
  })  

  .state('add-tags', {
      url: '/add-tags',
      templateUrl: 'templates/publish-msg/publishmsg-form-tags.html',
      controller: 'publishMessageFormTagController'
  })
```

`publishMessageController.js`

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers",['ionic','ngTagsInput','angular-carousel'])
.controller("publishMessageController",function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $cordovaToast, deviceStatus){

  $scope.gotoAddTag = function()
  {
    $location.path('add-tags');
  }
```

`publishMessageFormTagController.js`

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers",['ionic'])
.controller("publishMessageFormTagController",function($scope, $http, $location, $ionicLoading, $cordovaToast, deviceStatus){
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="js/controllers/publishMessageFormTagController.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers/publishMessageController.js"></script>
```

Now inside `publishmsg-form.html`

```
<div class="item formTagList" ng-click='gotoAddTag()' id="publishMsgFormTags">
```

when i call `gotoAddTag()` it throw

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'publishMessageFormTagController' is not a function, got undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your reinitializing the module see below case,

**publishMessageController.js**

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers",['ionic','ngTagsInput','angular-carousel'])
```

**publishMessageFormTagController.js**

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers",['ionic'])
```

in here second module declaration will override the first one

so you need something like

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers").controller("publishMessageFormTagController",function($s....
```

note that second array argument pass to `angular.module()` is not present here, so that angular will get the previous module which your defined and attach the controller `publishMessageFormTagController` to that module. If the argument array is present then angular will override the first module and assign the `publishMessageFormTagController` to the module but since it overriding the first one angular can't find the controller `publishMessageController`.

Comment: does the order of including bothe controller js file also matter ?